# How to be invisible on whatsapp?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

It’s related to a specific user and a specific group.

I don’t want to block that user and don’t want to quite that group.

Whenever that user send me a content (text, image or video) or whenever anyone share a content in a group; I want to see all contents but I do not want them (a specific user and members of group) to know that the contents have been delivered to me and I have seen the contents.

Also, if I am online, I do not want them (a specific user and a specific group members) to know that I am online.

Please let me know.

What settings are required for both?

Regards

Smith

Comment: Currently being invisible or not accepting messages from a particular member in a group is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

There are apps that get around the limitations you mentioned, and they're able to retrieve the messages without you opening WhatsApp.

There are many similar apps on the play store, one of them is called [private read for WhatsApp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.frankyapps.privateread.prws) it displays the messages and media in it's own app without you having to open WhatsApp, this way you can view the content without the other person knowing. I've never tried the app, and so I cannot vouch for it's accuracy.

As for hiding the fact that you are online while using Whatsapp, you should first disable your *last seen* from WhatsApp settings, and then, every time you want to open WhatsApp, you should put your phone into *airplane mode*. That way no-one will be able to see that you're online. (The messages will be sent after you exit WhatsApp, and go out of airplane mode)

Answer (score 1):

You can become practically invisible to all, from both sides, by  executing the following steps.

- Disable the read receipts
- Disable the Last seen

If you want even more security, Download Whatsapp Business edition. Its got even more high ended privacy settings and analysis as well.

Comment: Read receipts are only disabled for private chat. They will still appear while in group chat. Turning off last seen will still show when you're online

Answer (score 0):

You can't [be 100% invisible on WhatsApp](https://www.howtochatonline.net/chat-apps/whatsapp/how-to-be-invisible-on-whatsapp/) since online status has a default settings which you can't change at all. However there are ways to improve your invisibility.

1. Set your last seen to nobody.
2. Set your status to "Only Share with". (Add one or a few people)
3. Block contacts that you don't want to talk temporarily.
4. Disable read receipts
5. Set your profile picture to nobody.

These will improve your invisibility on the application. You can also do the plane mode trick to read messages if you don't want others to see you have received messages from them.